# CentOS 7 cannot install php-imap extension

Tags: php, centos, centos7, php-7.2

I am trying to install imap extension on a CentOS 7 server with PHP version 7.2.23. I tried the command `yum install php-imap` and output is

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                              |  21 kB  00:00:00
 * base: mirrors.vangus.co.il
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
 * remi-php72: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
base                                                                                                              | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                                              | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
mariadb                                                                                                           | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
remi-php72                                                                                                        | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
remi-safe                                                                                                         | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
(1/2): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                     | 1.0 MB  00:00:00
(2/2): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                     | 6.9 MB  00:00:00
No package php-imap available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

So I googled and found out that we can install from epel repository. So I ran the command  `yum list *imap*` and I am getting

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.vangus.co.il
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
 * remi-php72: mirror.23media.com
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
 * updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net
Available Packages
cyrus-imapd.x86_64                                              2.4.17-15.el7                                                        base
cyrus-imapd-devel.i686                                          2.4.17-15.el7                                                        base
cyrus-imapd-devel.x86_64                                        2.4.17-15.el7                                                        base
cyrus-imapd-utils.x86_64                                        2.4.17-15.el7                                                        base
imapfilter.x86_64                                               2.6.15-1.el7                                                         epel
imapsync.noarch                                                 1.727-1.el7                                                          epel
imaptest.x86_64                                                 20151005-1.el7                                                       epel
offlineimap.noarch                                              6.7.0-1.el7                                                          epel
perl-Mail-IMAPClient.noarch                                     3.37-1.el7                                                           epel
python-abimap-doc.noarch                                        0.3.1-3.el7                                                          epel
python36-abimap.noarch                                          0.3.1-3.el7                                                          epel
up-imapproxy.x86_64                                             1.2.8-0.12.20171022svn14722.el7                                      epel
uw-imap.x86_64                                                  2007f-16.el7                                                         epel
uw-imap-devel.x86_64                                            2007f-16.el7                                                         epel
uw-imap-static.x86_64                                           2007f-16.el7                                                         epel
uw-imap-utils.x86_64                                            2007f-16.el7                                                         epel
```

How can I install imap extension for PHP? Please help.

Comment: How did you install the epel repo? yum install epel?

Comment: @RamanSailopal  It was already there.

Answer (score 0):

Using a proper configuration, from the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions, install should work

```
# dnf install php-imap
Dependencies resolved.
====================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                     Arch                Version                     Repository                 Size
====================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 php-imap                    x86_64              7.2.34-4.el7.remi           remi-php72                       89 k
Installing dependencies:
 libc-client                 x86_64              2007f-16.el7                epel                                      562 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  2 Packages

Total download size: 651 k
Installed size: 1.7 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

> - base: mirrors.vangus.co.il
> - epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
> - extras: mirror.ratiokontakt.de
> - remi-php72: mirror.23media.com
> - remi-safe: mirror.23media.com
> - updates: mirror.fra10.de.leaseweb.net

Hmm... looks good

Package [php-imap](https://mirror.23media.com/remi/enterprise/7/php72/x86_64/repoview/php-imap.html) exists and should be found

Please check yum enabled plugins, or try with --noplugins options

Please also be aware that **PHP 7.2 has reached its end of life** in November 2020, so you should consider using a [supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Comment: Thanks, but  `yum install --noplugins php-imap` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your centos/Rocky version: For me on Rocky 9 just now (installing php 8.0):

```
dnf install epel-release
dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-9.rpm
```

Then remove any previous php install

```
dnf remove php*
dnf module reset php
dnf module install php:remi-8.0

dnf install php-imap
```

Gives you access to more modules than just imap; obviously add the others as needed. Change the rpm URL based on your Distro version E.g. Centos/Rocky 8, Rocky 9 etc.. Change the php:remi command based on which php version you want (e.g. 8.0 in the example above).